# What is the proof that the existence of one-way-functions implies $P \neq NP$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I am not an expert in this field, but I have read that the existence of one-way functions implies $P \neq NP$. Since there seem to be so many different definitions of one-way-functions and I have not seen a proof  I wanted to ask if someone knows where to read this, or knows the proof. 
Please if you give a proof, also give a precise definition of which version of "one-way-function" you use. The proof can of course be detailed, the detailed, the better! :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $P=NP$ and there is a one-way function $f$. You know $f$ is computed by a poly-size circuit. Given $y$, can you think of a way to find $x$ with $f(x)=y$?

Comment: I guess the poly-size circuit problem is in NP, so since by assumption P=NP, we can solve the poly-size circuit problem in polynomial time and thus invert $f$ which contradicts the assumption that $f$ is one-way. But I didn't know of the connection of $f$ to the poly-size circuit problem. Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: Assuming $P=NP$, there is an algorithm that takes as input a circuit computing a function $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, outputs $x$ with $f(x)=1$ if such an $x$ exists, and runs in time polynomial in $n$ and the size of the circuit.

Comment: Ok, but how does one construct an $NP$ complete problem given a one-way-function (Definition of Wikipedia)?

Comment: If a function is one way then its inverse is at least as hard as an NP complete problem.

Comment: Checking whether a given circuit has a satisfying assignment is an NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$P \ne NP$ if and only if worst-case one-way functions exist.

Reference:

Alan L. Selman. A survey of one-way functions in complexity theory. Mathematical systems theory, 25(3):203–221, 1992.

Comment: it would be helpful to sketch out/ summarize some of the proof.

Answer (score 6):

If P=NP, every polytime computable 1-1 function $f$ has a polytime computable inverse:
$\{(x,y) \mid \exists z\ |yz| \leq poly(|x|) \land f(yz)=x \}$ is NP. 
We can find a $y$ such that $f(y)=x$ by starting with the empty string as$y$ and greedily adding the following bits using this NP oracle.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:\{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ be a OWF and define $L_f = \{(x,y)\in \{0,1\}^* \times \{0,1\}^*:$ there exists $z$ such that $f(xz)=y\}$.
I construct the following non-deterministic Turing machine:
$A((x,y)):$"Non-deterministically guess $z$. return ACCEPT if $f(xz)=y$ and REJECT otherwise"
$A$ makes a single call to $f$ which is OWF and therefore runs in polynomial time. $A$ decides $L_f$ therefore $L_f \in NP$.

Assuming $P=NP$, there exists a deterministic polynomial time decider $A'$ such that $A'((x,y)) = ACCEPT \iff A((x,y)) = ACCEPT$. Using $A'$ I construct $f'$ which inverts $f$ in deterministic polynomial time. First, I define a helper function $h:(\{0,1\}^*,\{0,1\}^*) \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ the following way:

$h(x,y) = $
\begin{cases}
    h(x0,y),& \text{if } A'(x0, y) = ACCEPT\\
    h(x1,y),& \text{if } A'(x1, y) = ACCEPT\\
 x  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

$h$ is a recursive function that tries to add a single bit $b$ to $x$ in every iteration. If $A'$ accepts $xb$, that means there exists some $z$ such that $f(xbz) = y$. In this case, $h$ recalls itself with $xb$. Once $|z| = 0$ I know parameter $x$ contains the preimage of $y$ and the DTM $A'$ would reject both $(x0,y)$ and $(x1,y)$. In this case $h$ returns $x$. $h$ runs in deterministic polynomial time in $|xz|$ since at every iteration $|x|$ grows by 1 on account of $|z|$. At every iteration $h$ calls $A'$ which runs in polynomial time, making the total runtime of $h$ polynomial.

Using $h$ I define the function $f':\{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ such that $f'(y) = $ "Initialize $x$ to be empty and return $h(x,y)$". $f'$ inverts $f$ in deterministic polynomial therefore $f$ is not OWF, reaching contradiction.
In conclusion, if there exists a OWF, then $P \neq NP$.

Comment: If P=NP, any polytime computable 1-1 function has a polytime computable inverse. The proof is not even a paragraph: $\{(x,y) \mid \exists z\ |yz| \leq poly(|x|) \land f(yz)=x \}$ is NP. We can find a $y$ by starting at empty string and greedily adding the following bits using this NP oracle.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: It was already hinted under the question. Your answer is too long for this basic question imo. Anyone who has seen a reduction from search to decision should be able to fill out the rest.

Comment: Every point in my answer is a necessary logical step.

Comment: Not on this site. Have you checked [help/on-topic]? If someone cannot fill in the gaps like these then probably they should ask the question on our sister site [cs.se] in place of here.